# How add column order in careers table?

Tags: mysql

this table i want to create

```
job_id            dynamic
Jobs Title        text
Job Description   text
job_Order         combo box to choose after what job 
                    or at first position in the website
```

i create form to add job and i want to create combo box to choose how will view in first position in career page. i using job_id to choose first position and when select data will call order by job_order

this is true or another solution

thank you

Comment: Can you make your question clearer? As it is, people are basically guessing at what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking how to sort data using an SQL request? If so, you need to use an ORDER BY statement. However, if you're seeking a solution using a specific programming language (php, java, c#...) it would be a good idea to add a tag or two to indicate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select *, case when job_Order is null then 1 else 0 end as Rank
from job
order by Rank, job_Order, job_id
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'm reading is this: The user will add a job on one page using job_id as the reference. You're question is how to sort the jobs on the career page? Can you not just "ORDER BY job_Order" when retrieving the data to display on the careers page?